# Postresql: How do I UPDATE null values in column with values from another table?

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

Using PostgreSQL 9.2.4 ... I have three tables:

sales: 
inventoryid, batchno, quantity 
00001, A40-0007, 1 
00002, NULL, 1 
00003, C20-0039, 2

parts: 
partid, name 
8, A40 
5, B30 
3, C20

inventory: 
inventoryid, partid, batcho 
00001, 8, A40-0007 
00002, 5, NULL 
00003, 3, C20-0039

How do I UPDATE all of the NULL values in sales.batchno with the matching part name? 
 In the end, I want the sales table to look like this: 
 
sales: 
inventoryid, batchno, quantity 
00001, A40-0007, 1 
00002, B30, 1 
00003, C20-0039, 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `update ... from`:

```
update sales s
set batchno = p.name
from inventory i 
inner join parts p on p.partid = i.partid
where i.inventoryid = s.inventoryid and s.batchno is null
```

Note that your design has duplicated information, so it does not look optimal.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you for all of your help!